# Shrinking boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm, math

I am pulling my hair out, trying to solve a simple problem. I know there is some math step here that I am missing and I feel like I am right on the edge of the solution but I just can't get there.

What I am trying to do is write an algorithm to fill an element with squares, and once the element is filled, resize the squares, create a new row and keep filling. Once both new rows are filled, append another row. Basically a line feed type algorithm?

So what I have so far works on the first row, but fails after that as it keeps resizing the unnecessarily.

```
$(function(){ //DOM Ready

  //get columns of even squares
  var columns = parseInt($(".grid").width()/$(".grid").height());
  var rows = 1;  


  function checkSize(ico,index){

   var grid,gridWidth,gridHeight
   var icon,iconWidth,iconHeight

   //get our grid info
     grid  = $(".grid");
     gridWidth = grid.width();
     gridHeight= grid.height();

   //get our icon info
     icon = $(ico);
     iconWidth = icon.outerWidth();
     iconHeight = icon.outerHeight();





    //will go over columns?
    if(index >= columns){

     //do we need another row?
      if(Math.floor(gridHeight/iconHeight) === rows){

          //add row
          rows++;

         //reset columns
        columns = gridWidth / Math.floor(gridHeight / rows);  

         //resize boxes
         size();


          };





    }


   };

  function size(){

    var grid,icon,newHeight;

    grid = $(".grid");
    newHeight = (grid.height()/rows)

    $.each(grid.children(".icon"),function(index,value){

      icon = $(value);
      icon.css("height",newHeight+'px');
      icon.css("width",newHeight+'px');
     });


  }



  //fill
  var counter = 0;
  function fillGrid(){

   var icon,grid,r,g,b,a

   icon = $('<div class="icon"></div>');

   //random color 
   r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   a = 1;
   icon.css('background-color','rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+','+a+')')


   grid = $(".grid");

   grid.append(icon);
   size(icon);
   checkSize(icon,counter);
   counter++; 

  };

  var timeoutID;
  function start(){
    if(timeoutID){
      clearInterval(timeoutID);
      timeoutID = undefined;
    }else{
       timeoutID = window.setInterval(fillGrid, 1000);
    }



    };

   //START THE TIMER
  $('#start').on('click',start);





});
```

See the working example here-

http://jsbin.com/ovewib/7/edit

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post some code in the question itself, please.

Comment: @Blazemonger There are warnings (mostly about semicolons), but no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
 //will go over columns?
 if (index >= columns) {
```

This is counting wrong when there is more than one row. Try this instead:

```
 //will go over columns?
 if (index >= Math.floor(columns)*rows) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zXeHG/

Comment: Bah, Blazemonger beat me to it.  The one suggestion I would recommend is to do the Math.floor when evaluating columns lower down.  You never want it to be non-integer.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you!